# ExtJS 6 thousand separator in number field

Tags: javascript, extjs, numbers, separator, extjs6

How to make ExtJS (6) number field `numberfield` to show thousand separator? It is not supported by default in `Number` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution I found is to override `Ext.form.field.Number`class. Below is my code. However, you can find it on [github](https://github.com/PragmaticDeveloper/ExtJS-Overrides-Number).

The thousand separator feature is controlled by `allowThousandSeparator` property.

The code is aware of localization.

```
Ext.define("some.package.ThousandSeparatorNumber", {
    override: "Ext.form.field.Number",

    /**
     * @cfg {Boolean} allowThousandSeparator
     * False to disallow thousand separator feature.
     */
    allowThousandSeparator: true,

    /**
     * @private
     */
    toBaseNumber: function(value) {
        var me = this;
        return String(value).replace(new RegExp("[" + Ext.util.Format.thousandSeparator + "]", "g"), '').replace(me.decimalSeparator, '.');
    },

    /**
     * @private
     */
    parseRawValue: function(value) {
        var me = this;
        value = parseFloat(me.toBaseNumber(value));
        return isNaN(value) ? null : value;
    },

    getErrors: function(value) {
        if (!this.allowThousandSeparator)
            return this.callParent(arguments);
        value = arguments.length > 0 ? value : this.processRawValue(this.getRawValue());

        var me = this,
            errors = me.callSuper([value]),
            format = Ext.String.format,
            num;

        if (value.length < 1) { // if it's blank and textfield didn't flag it then it's valid
            return errors;
        }

        value = me.toBaseNumber(value);

        if (isNaN(value)) {
            errors.push(format(me.nanText, value));
        }

        num = me.parseValue(value);

        if (me.minValue === 0 && num < 0) {
            errors.push(this.negativeText);
        } else if (num < me.minValue) {
            errors.push(format(me.minText, me.minValue));
        }

        if (num > me.maxValue) {
            errors.push(format(me.maxText, me.maxValue));
        }

        return errors;
    },

    rawToValue: function(rawValue) {
        if (!this.allowThousandSeparator)
            return this.callParent(arguments);
        var value = this.fixPrecision(this.parseRawValue(rawValue));
        if (value === null) {
            value = rawValue || null;
        }
        return value;
    },

    valueToRaw: function(value) {
        if (!this.allowThousandSeparator) {
            return this.callParent(arguments);
        }
        var me = this,
            decimalSeparator = me.decimalSeparator,
            format = "0,000";
        if (me.allowDecimals) {
            for (var i = 0; i < me.decimalPrecision; i++) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    format += ".";
                }
                format += "0";
            }
        }
        value = me.parseValue(value);
        value = me.fixPrecision(value);
        value = Ext.isNumber(value) ? value : parseFloat(String(value).replace(decimalSeparator, '.'));
        value = isNaN(value) ? '' : Ext.util.Format.number(value, format);
        return value;
    },

    getSubmitValue: function() {
        if (!this.allowThousandSeparator)
            return this.callParent();
        var me = this,
            value = me.callSuper();

        if (!me.submitLocaleSeparator) {
            value = me.toBaseNumber(value);
        }
        return value;
    },

    setMinValue: function(value) {
        if (!this.allowThousandSeparator)
            return this.callParent(arguments);
        var me = this,
            ariaDom = me.ariaEl.dom,
            minValue, allowed, ariaDom;

        me.minValue = minValue = Ext.Number.from(value, Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY);
        me.toggleSpinners();

        // May not be rendered yet
        if (ariaDom) {
            if (minValue > Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY) {
                ariaDom.setAttribute('aria-valuemin', minValue);
            } else {
                ariaDom.removeAttribute('aria-valuemin');
            }
        }

        // Build regexes for masking and stripping based on the configured options
        if (me.disableKeyFilter !== true) {
            allowed = me.baseChars + '';

            if (me.allowExponential) {
                allowed += me.decimalSeparator + 'e+-';
            } else {
                allowed += Ext.util.Format.thousandSeparator;
                if (me.allowDecimals) {
                    allowed += me.decimalSeparator;
                }
                if (me.minValue < 0) {
                    allowed += '-';
                }
            }

            allowed = Ext.String.escapeRegex(allowed);
            me.maskRe = new RegExp('[' + allowed + ']');
            if (me.autoStripChars) {
                me.stripCharsRe = new RegExp('[^' + allowed + ']', 'gi');
            }
        }
    }
});
```